# Multi color cell formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to have a column of cells fill with one of 3 colors based on it's value in relation to another cell or the sum of other cells.
Column A, Column B and Column C. Column A is the colored column.
A to be green if A is greater than B
A to be orange if A is less than B but A+C is greater than B
A to be red if A is less B and less than A+C.
I have tried using standard fill of green with also conditional formatting "use a formula to determine which cells to format 2 color scale but have been unsuccessful.
I appreciate any help you may give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is really straightforward, but you need to realise that you can have different rules within conditional formatting. Let me show you in a screenshot (sorry for the Dutch, "Celwaarde" means "cell value"):

[image]

In order to create one rule, you might do it as follows (use the second option):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is exactly what I ended up successfully doing. As you stated, it was very simple. Thanks again.